# Save to server side file from PHP via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to save a json string from a javascript file to a local file on the server using PHP, however, my json file is not being modified at all.
Here is my Javascript:

```
function saveToFile(data){
  jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/save.php',
    data : jsonString,
    type: 'POST'
  });
}
```

Note that jsonString is a valid variable, and i can log it correctly into the console.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
  $data = $_POST['jsonString'];
  $f = fopen("../website-contents.json", "w") or die("fopen failed");
  fwrite($f, $data) or die("fwrite failed");
  fclose($f);
?>
```

Note that even tests trying to save "Hello World" to "test.txt" don't work, or through errors.

Finally, here is my folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Try var_dumping your $_POST variable, might give you some more insight.  The key 'jsonString' is most likely incorrect on the php side.

Comment: `file_put_contents( $uploadLocation."/filename.json", $fileJsonString );` Make sure you have the correct write permissions on where you are going to save this.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: @crowebird I echoed my $data and its all correct, however, its giving me the "fopen failed" error from my or die.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah the response is giving me the fopen error, have set the permissions (i think) for the whole of my /home/user/html directory, which is where my server is running

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Here is your solution.
>
> Js code

```
function saveToFile(data){
  jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/save.php',
    data : {'jsonString':jsonString},
    type: 'POST'
  });
}
```

> php code.

```
$data = $_POST['jsonString'];
//set mode of file to writable.
chmod("../website-contents.json",0777);
$f = fopen("../website-contents.json", "w+") or die("fopen failed");
fwrite($f, $data);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: The data is being parsed in correctly now, thank you! However, i am getting the message "fopen failed", even after setting the chmod. Is the path within fopen relative to the PHP/JS or absolute?

Comment: can you use `$f = fopen("../website-contents.json", "w+");` instead of `$f = fopen("../website-contents.json", "w+") or die("fopen failed");` and check the error ? So i can better understand what is happening here.

Comment: It was just a permissions error in the end, setting "sudo chmod 777 website-contents.json" solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments pointing out you must have a permission problem. However, it will not work after you have corrected this problem either. You have

```
$data = $_POST['jsonString'];
```

but where do you set a key called `jsonString`? Use

```
function saveToFile(data){
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.post("php/save.php", {
     jsonString: jsonString
  })
}
```

instead.